# Javascript array compare elements

Tags: javascript

I have an array with dates and I want to take the last value from array for each month. How can I do that? I have this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < vm.openDatesToSave.length; i++) {
            var c = vm.openDatesToSave[i].getMonth();
            for (var j = i+1; j < vm.openDatesToSave.length; j++) {
                var d = vm.openDatesToSave[j].getMonth();
                if (d === c) {
                    a.push(vm.openDatesToSave[j]);
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

For example, I want to take Jan 09, Feb 06 and Mar 14.

Comment: any sample inputs?

Comment: is the result of `getMonth` a string or number or Date object?

Comment: @havenchyk number

Comment: @havenchyk it is a number

Comment: expected output any input and output samples?

Comment: what is the value of vm.openDatesToSave?

Comment: @ABUdhay It's an array of date objects - see the use of `.getMonth()`

Comment: you need the last day of every month in the array?

Comment: @zabusa last day added in array for every month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var dates = [
 new Date( '2018-02-14' ),
 new Date( '2018-01-17' ),
 new Date( '2018-02-06' ),
 new Date( '2018-01-09' ),
 new Date( '2018-03-14' )
];
// We want to transform an array of dates into a shorter summary. So we use reduce to turn multiple values into less values.
// By using a object as the output, we get an easy summary which can be turned back into an array if needed.
var lastDatesPerMonth = dates.reduce( function( months, date ) {
 // months are zero-based, so + 1
 var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
 // Always overwrite the correct month with the new date.
 months[ month ] = date;
 return months;
}, {} );

console.log( lastDatesPerMonth );
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var dates = [new Date('2018-05-12'), new Date('2018-04-03'), new Date('2018-05-04')];

var result = dates.reduce((acc, item) => {
   const month = item.getMonth(); 
   acc[month] = item;
   return acc;
},{})

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using lodash, then

```
lastDays = _.map(_.groupBy(dates, d => d.getMonth()), _.last)
```

otherwise consider using it.

rant: I fail to see why SO keeps preferring convoluted and fragile ad-hoc solutions to an established, efficient and tested library, end rant ;)

Comment: Own opinion: Because it teaches people how javascript actually works without abstracting away any of the details. Every time I see a coworker fail to write a simple reduction because his lib of choice doesn't have it builtin, I cry a bit inside. SO opinion: If the original post does not include a library, you are expected to psot a result without a library.

Comment: @Shilly: everytime I see a coworker writing a "reduction", although our lib does provide it out of the box, I feel the same ;)

Comment: That's the advantage of working in a consistent enviroment where everyone uses the same tools. If you have a library, learn to use it completely. If you don't have a library though, you need to know how to solve the issue in raw code. In the end it's the same problem, people not knowing the full power of the tools they use.

Comment: @Shilly: that's right, but in day-to-day programming you hardly write "raw" code. You write tools to automate repetitive tasks. You don't write a reducer everytime if you need to group objects, you just create a generic `groupBy` function and use it henceforth. Still, here on SO, when someone asks about grouping, people are rushing to show off their reduces instead of saying hey, it's a solved problem, here's your generic groupBy.

Comment: Most of the time these questions get asked by people who have no idea what functional programming is. Compare both our solutions. Yours is obviously way better, but it is also more complex for beginners to even understand how or why it works. It's like those posts suggesting 'use SASS' to people who still use JQuery to change style inline. I learned more on MDN about functional programming from one clear reduce example in JS than from reading the docs of the lib of the moment. Anwyays, you're 100% correct. I just believe that starting programmers should not skip steps while learning.

Comment: @Shilly: yep, that's right. Silly questions -> silly answers -> more silly questions, that's entropy for ya. ;)

Comment: Strangely enough entropy works both ways in this case. ;) What does that `=>` mean? Whats the underscore doing? What is a `.last`? My physics teacher always told me: "There are no silly questions, only silly answers."  I hope I can be in a position one day that this discussion is irrelevant because it'll be part of an actual standardLib without dependencies to stuff like leftpad. Thanks for the insights and have a nice weekend. :)

Comment: @Shilly: thank you too. Sorry if that sounded direct.

Comment: No worries. Was thinking the same thing, if my last comment didn't come across as sarcastic or hostile. Anyways, I was just thinking about the progression one makes when learning loops. s1: for loops due to learning. s2: array methods and lotsa shorthands due to coolness. s3: for loops ebcause we think we need to care about nanoseconds. s4: array methods without shorthands for readability. s5: for loops because realtime game. :D

Comment: @Shilly: you probably already know it, but still: https://www.willamette.edu/~fruehr/haskell/evolution.html

Comment: Although I don't grok all of the haskell, it's quite hilarious and true at the same time. It makes sense to each writer to do it that particular way. Thanks again, I'll be rereading it a few more times to learn the nuances in the examples.